# Can't access published port on a service on my host machine

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm, docker-network

The docker daemon is running on an Ubuntu machine. I'm trying to start up a zookeeper ensemble in a swarm. The zookeeper nodes themselves can talk to each other. However, from the host machine, I don't seem to be able to access the published ports.

If I start the container with -

`docker run \
-p 2181:2181 \
--env ZOO_MY_ID=1 \
--env ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888" \
zookeeper`

It works like a charm. On my host machine I can say `echo conf | nc localhost 2181` and zookeeper says something back.

However if I do,

`docker service create \
-p 2181:2181 \
--env ZOO_MY_ID=1 \
--env ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888" \
zookeeper`

and run the same command `echo conf | nc localhost 2181`,
it just gets stuck. I don't even get a new prompt on my terminal.

This works just as expected on the Docker Playground on the official Zookeeper Docker Hub page. So I expect it should for me too.

But... If I `docker exec -it $container sh` and then try the command in there, it works again.
Aren't published ports supposed to be accessible even by the host machine for a service?

Is there some trick I'm missing about working with overlay networks?

Comment: What do you see when you perform a 'docker service ps --no-trunc zookeeper'?

Comment: There is nothing listed under ports when I run that command if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: However if I do 'docker service ls' under ports it says
' *:2181->2181/tcp '

Comment: Actually I was expecting some failed container in "current state". Did you see anything of intersest in service logs? (docker service logs zookeeper)
  Do you run both your 'run' and 'service create' command under the same machine? Also I suppose you checked /etc/hosts for localhost presence?

Comment: localhost exists in the hosts file. Logs don't even register the request from the host. the `nc` command just gets stuck. But if I `docker exec` into a container and run the commands the logs reflect the `nc` request. And yes. Both the run and service create commands were tested on the same node.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `docket service create --publish 2181:2181` instead.

I believe the container backing the service is not directly exposed and has to go through the Swarm networking.

Otherwise, inspect your service to check which port are published: `docker service inspect <service_name>`

Source: [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#/publish-a-port-for-a-service)

Comment: inspect shows that the port 2181 is published. However it's the same issue. The issue persists on using ' --publish ' too.